# Is there a way to "copy" calculated fields from one data source to another (not referring to duplicating calc-field in same data source)?

Tags: looker-studio

I have several "copies" of the same datasource that have different calculated fields. Is there a way to merge all of the different calculated fields into a single Datasource I'm hoping there's a process to do this other than manually doing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported.